# CloudSim server

Tags: cloudsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to install CloudSim on some local server too? From tutorials it's not clear to me... Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/621/cloudsim-server/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It is possible to deploy CloudSim itself on a local machine.  We do that regularly for development and testing.  See the [developer instructions](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/CloudSim/development).

But it's not possible to deploy a Gazebo installation onto a local machine using CloudSim.  That step will be done on a cloud-hosted machine.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0